# Download uploaded cspkg file from Azure

Tags: azure

Can I download the cspkg from Azure that I uploaded (rather than reuploading new package)?

The scenario is -

I need to add files into existing website - let say an image.

I rdp and add manually; however, Azure recreates a new instance and wipe out my files when my instance behaves so abnormally.

(Ideally, I should store them in storage, but the question is not about that.)

Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[The paragraph below is incorrect]**

Currently there is no API or mechanism which can download the exact same CSPKG directly from Windows Azure Portal which was uploaded. This sure is a big requirement from Windows Azure user specially when you loose your Windows Azure Project/Solution.

**[Edit- Correction to above paragraph]**

Using ["Get Package"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj154121.aspx) REST API you can download the package from specific deployment to your Azure Blog storage. IF you decide to write your own C# application to use REST API the sample is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg651127.aspx). If you don't want to write API and just download the package using REST call, there are a few tools and I have used [BURP (based on Java)](http://portswigger.net/burp/downloadfree.html) as described in my blog [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/05/16/windows-azure-management-using-burp-java-based-gui-tool-and-rest-api.aspx). You can use the info in the blog to setup connect to Azure Portal and then use REST call as documented to get the package.

Next even if you download the CSPKG (or have a local copy of CSPKG) still you can not edit it by  adding or removing any content directly to it because this will break the CSPKG package integrity and you will get an error uploading it. The package must be created using CSPACK tool.

The Drive E:\ where your approot is does include most of your compiled code so if you can download it locally and come up with an idea to build a new project form that (???), that could be an option. If the package was created directly using CSPACK tool and the downloading the files from drive E:\ and recreating the package does work however if the project the a complex application included source and compiled code files i.e. ASP.NET/MVCx application, it is tough.

Comment: Avkash -> I beg to differ on your 1st statement that you can't download CSPKG file. Recently Service Management API team introduced a new function called "Get Package" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj154121.aspx) which allows you to do just that.

Comment: Gaurav, I do agree with your comment and just verify that using Get Package command the package can be retrieved from the specific subscription to specific Azure Blob storage. I tested with Burp and could get the package so I will update the answer above. Somehow I was under impression this REST interface is still not available publically. My mistake!!

Answer (score 3):

I faced the similar issue,

What I did was,

Use [`Get-Package`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj154121.aspx) REST API calls to store `cspkg` and `cscfg` files in a storage container.

**Remember this storage container should be in under the same subscription, otherwise Get-Package REST API calls will fail.**

Then I used AzCopy (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/12/03/azcopy-uploading-downloading-files-for-windows-azure-blobs.aspx) , to copy files from the storage container to my local disks.

You can also use AzCopy to copy from one StorageContainer to another, even under different subscriptions.

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Thank You! Key thing is that storage account should be in the same subscription as that of the Cloud Service.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [Windows Azure Service Management Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceManagement.Library) NuGet Package, the C# code to get the package becomes:

```
private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string storeName, string thumbprint)
{
    var store = new X509Store(storeName);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    return store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, true)[0];
}

public static void ExportPackage(X509Certificate2 certificate, string subscriptionId, string serviceName, string deploymentName, string containerUri)
{
    var managementService = ServiceManagementHelper.CreateServiceManagementChannel("WindowsAzureEndPoint", certificate);

    try
    {
        managementService.GetPackage(
            subscriptionId,
            serviceName,
            deploymentName,
            containerUri,
            true /*overwriteExisting*/);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Net.WebException exception = ex.InnerException as System.Net.WebException;
        if (exception != null)
        {
            string responseText;

            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(exception.Response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR:" + exception);
                Console.WriteLine(responseText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem, however, is that no matter what I pass in as the containerUri, I get back 400 Bad request - Parameter value 'something.blob.core.windows.net/somecontainer'; specified for parameter 'ContainerUriString' is invalid.

**Update:** my problem was due to the storage container belonging to a different subscription - that was obviously not working. I made sure the container belonged to the same subscription, and voila!

**Update**: This code assumes the following app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WindowsAzureServiceManagement_WebHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
                <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="1048576" maxBytesPerRead="131072"/>
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint name="WindowsAzureEndPoint" address="https://management.core.windows.net" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WindowsAzureServiceManagement_WebHttpBinding" contract="Microsoft.Samples.WindowsAzure.ServiceManagement.IServiceManagement" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

or, alternatively, for LinqPad users, you can configure web service inline as follows:

```
        var b = new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
        b.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
        var address = new EndpointAddress("https://management.core.windows.net");
        var managementService = ServiceManagementHelper.CreateServiceManagementChannel(b, address.Uri, certificate);
```

Typical use:

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = GetCertificate("My", "NNNNNNNNNNNNN");
ExportPackage(certificate,
            "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "yourservice",
            "00000000000000000000000000000000",
            "https://yourstorage.blob.core.windows.net/container");
```

Comment: This works well. Depending on where the certificate is stored locally it may be necessary to specify the store: `var store = new X509Store(storeName, StoreLocation.LocalMachine)`.

Comment: added inline configuration of the service without the need of app.config - for LinqPad lovers as myself :)

Comment: also - keep in mind that the certificate must be MANAGEMENT one - installed for subscription, not the deployment certificate used for uploading the builds.